# HOW TO MAP COLUMN GENERATED COLUMN ALWAYS AS.... at MariaDB TO Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, performance, mariadb

I have a column in mariadb called operator_tax_info, with the following structure,

```
CREATE TABLE `operator_tax_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `operator_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `geolocation` point NOT NULL,
  `data` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL CHECK (json_valid(`data`)),
  `fiscal_number` varchar(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`data`,'$.fiscal_number'))) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `operator_tax_info_operator_id_0c173d85_fk_companies_operator_id` (`operator_id`),
  SPATIAL KEY `operator_tax_info_geolocation_id` (`geolocation`),
  KEY `fiscal_number` (`fiscal_number`),
  CONSTRAINT `operator_tax_info_operator_id_0c173d85_fk_companies_operator_id` FOREIGN KEY (`operator_id`) REFERENCES `companies_operator` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=639 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

as you can see the column fiscal_number is a generated column from data column which is a json field, that column was recently added, to get fiscal_number from the json, and also as  backend we use Django 3.2 as our ORM, with the following Model definition:

```
class OperatorTaxInfo(BaseModel, SoftDeletionModel):
    operator = models.ForeignKey(
        'companies.Operator', related_name='operator_tax_info_operator', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    data = JSONField(default=dict)        
    geolocation = geomod.PointField('Geo_localizacion', default=Point(0, 0))

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'operator_tax_info'
```

So my question is there a way to map this column from mariadb to Django, or how to generate this column from Django using migrations and indexes, without losing speed from db, because I have trying using a @property decorator to map and annotate this column, but I think is not naive way to achieve  this column , specially if I need to filter from Django a fiscal_number

```
 @property
    def fiscal_number(self):
        # Use the Func class to apply the JSON_UNQUOTE and JSON_EXTRACT functions
        result = self.data.annotate(fiscal_number=Func(F('data'), Value('$.fiscal_number'), function='JSON_UNQUOTE'))
        return result.values_list('fiscal_number', flat=True).first()
```

Comment: In what action do you "lose speed from db"?  Inserts?  Selects?  Migrations?  Other?  (In my opinion, frameworks--where Django is only one of a hundred--cannot keep up with databases changes and hence do more to get in the way of building a non-trivial application.)

Comment: Yu can create a custom manager for your model to annotate your queryset with the fiscal_number field.

Comment: Thank you, for your comments Rick James , what I meant was when you make a query on sql it returns the date pretty fast,  I was trying to identify how to declare this field in Django as one more column, instead of genered always from db side, 


TSCAmerica.com would yoy give an example how to delcare the Custom Manager please is somethin similar to the property decorator?